# How to keep newline in Angular inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm noticing a behavior that I'm not intending for.  I have a `<textarea>` where if I can enter some text as seen below.

```
some content
some other content 
yet another content
```

When I'm saving this text into a JSON object and store it,  what I get is:

```
 "value" : "some content some other content yet another content"
```

Alternatively, I'll sometimes get this:

```
"value" : "some content
some other content      
yet another content"
```

I guess what I've been *expecting* to receive is:

```
"value" : "some content \n
    some other content \n     
    yet another content"
```

So that way I can present the content in the same way that it was input.

But this seems to break my `JSON.parse(string)`.
I'm using **AngluarJS** for models in inputs.

**EDIT:**

This is what happens if I put my Object in a JSON validator:
[image]

Comment: How are you saving the textarea's text?

Comment: I save it in an object. const data = { text : $scope.text } then I send it to my server which stores it in a rethink database. Is that it? Does it help?

Comment: Does it give error in javascript? (If yes, then it is a problem)... now if the _problem_ is because you are copying from console to an website, you can replace quotes `"` by backticks ``

Answer (score 2):

You could try and replace the newline characters with something else.
If the newline characters are causing issues with your `JSON.parse`, try to replace them with something else like `<br/>` which will act like a newline when you retrieve the data.

You could also try `JSON.stringify` on your `textarea` value before using `JSON.parse` which should convert your `textarea` value to a JSON string with visible newline characters.

```
document.getElementById("textarea-id").value.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />')
```

**OR**

```
JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("textarea-id").value)
```

See the `console.log`'s in the example below:
https://jsfiddle.net/fjj2psqj/1/

Comment: My problem is that I don't see the newline character anywhere. in the database it just does a newline without the  \n char

Comment: Yes the new line character wont be visible, but it exists in the string. If you do the replace like i've done above you will notice that the new lines in your text area will be replaced by <br/>.

Comment: ok I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
// valid JSON
var data = {
    "value": [
      "line",
      "line",
      "line"
    ]
};

// stringify the data to save it as text
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

// parse the string and join the array to recover line breaks
// or iterate over values array depending on your use case
var withNewLines = JSON.parse(dataString).value.join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run your captured textarea string through JSON.stringify before sending it to your server, and JSON.parse it before you use again in your application.

```
$scope.doSomethingWithTextareaText = function() {
    //assuming your textarea is bound to $scope.text
    $scope.myObject['value'] = $scope.text;
    $scope.myObject['stringifyValue'] = JSON.stringify($scope.text);
    /*
      $scope.myObject[value]: 
        some content
        some other content 
        yet another content
      $scope.myObject[stringifyValue]: 
        "some content\nsome other content\nyet another content"
      JSON.parse($scope.myObject[stringifyValue]): 
        some content
        some other content 
        yet another content
    */
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5d2oekv0/3/.